# How to root cause observeChanges() latency spikes?

Tags: meteor

I have a client that observes document additions using the [added callback mechanism](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-observeChanges).  Most of the time the added callback is fired ~2 seconds after document addition.   However, sometimes I will see spikes to as much as much as 20 seconds. i.e. document is added and the callback is executed 20 seconds later.

How can I root cause these spikes in callback execution latency?  Perhaps this is a network issue, how could I prove/disprove?

This is not a load issue as the number of clients and operations is constant.

I determine the time diff by placing a time stamp in the document inserted and then comparing with the time when the added callback is executed.

Not all clients experience these latency spikes.

Comment: Question number one is: Have you implemented oplog tailing? If not, start with that.

Comment: From googling [oplogging requires a replica set](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6015)?  As far as I know I am not using a replica set.

Comment: You can set up server and replica on the same instance. See https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6015, abernix comment on May 19.

Comment: If you are trying to rule out the network, open Dev Tools in Chrome, go to the Network tab, and view the WS (Websockes) traffic.  You will see the DDP messages for your records.  As long as the timestamps are all accurate, you should be able to calculate how long it took between the message coming across in DDP and when it was added to the minimongo of the client.  I'd also consider making your publication a custom one and adding some timing in there as well.